# Парсинг JSON: ошибка преобразования JSONObject в JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, парсер

Нужно распарсить json файл.
Поскольку раньше не работал с json файлами и вообще кодю под андройд недавно, то не могу никак распарсить и вывести json.
Перелопатил много сайтов, в том числе и гугловские доки - все ровно не хочет выводится. Начал переделывать имеющие примеры в интернете, что бы хоть как то разобраться, как это все работает, и все равно никак. Пробовал разные способы, в том числе и библиотеки GSON. Поэтому прошу вашей помощи. На данный момент имею такой код:

```
package twitter.com.com;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TwitterActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String str;
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StrictMode.enableDefaults();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView twitterMessages = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.twitter_messages);
        String readTwitterFeed = readTwitterFeed();
        StringBuilder messages = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            JSONArray  json = new JSONArray(readTwitterFeed);

            for (int i=0;i<json.length();i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject =  json.getJSONObject(i);
                String str = jsonObject.getString("title");
                messages.append(str+'\n');
            }
            twitterMessages.setText(messages.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public String readTwitterFeed() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("URL");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode ==200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.e(TwitterActivity.class.toString(), "Download fail");
            }
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Выдают логи :

> of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

JSON содержит следующие строки:

> {"list" : [{ "title" : "350.png", "description" : "1", "imageURL" :
>   "URL" },{ "title" : "Dom.jpg", "description" : "2", "imageURL" : "URL"
>   }.... и тп

Помогите пожалуйста, напишите как вывести правильно этот файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Распарсить данный файл довольно просто.
Для этого нужно выполнить следующие действия.
 1. Считать файл по сслылке
 Код:

```
                     try {
                      StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
                              ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                              StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
                      URL url = new URL("http://65apps.com/images/test1.json");
                      HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                      readStream(con.getInputStream());
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
              }
                    private void readStream(InputStream in) {
                      BufferedReader reader = null;
                      try {
                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                        while ((menu_txt = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            json_txt = menu_txt;
                        }
                      } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                      } finally {
                        if (reader != null) {
                          try {
                            reader.close();
                          } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                      }
```

1. Далее как видно Ваш файл считался и записался в переменную json_txt
   Теперь можно приступать к парсингу:(перед этим нужно знать(вспомнить), что **json** содержит объекты и массивы.
   **`Объектом`** является все, что идет после фигурной(**{**) скобки, а все что после квадратной(**[**)  **массивом**.

Так визульно распарсим Ваш файл и напишем код.

а) весь файл является объектом, поэтому создаем JSONOBject и передаем ему переменную json_txt в которой находится содержимое файла.

```
JSONObject jo =  new JSONObject(json_txt);
```

б) В объекте jo как видно сидит массив с идентификатором **list**, получим его:

```
JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONAray("list");
```

в) Теперь в этом массиве как видно через запятую идет серия объектов, значения из которых нам необходимо получить, для этого используем цикл for, со стопором равным длине массива **ja** `ja.length()`

```
String title, description, imageURL;

for(int i =0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
    //Получаем каждый объект из массива по отдельности
    JSONObject my_obj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
    //Получаем необходимые значения из объектов, по ключевым словам
    title = my_obj.getString("title");
    description = my_obj.getString("description");
    imageURL = my_obj.getString("imageURL");
    }
```

г) Теперь перейдем к созданию списка.

- создаем Layout c ListView;
- создаем Layout в котором содержится три текстовых поля для Ваших переменныхж
- Определяемся с адаптером.
- Передаем ему распарсенные значения, а он в свою очередь заполняет список.

К примеру:
Вы содали Layout'ы.

Вставляем в предыдущий код HashMap, в котором по ключ-значение записываются распарсенные данные:

```
String title, description, imageURL;
HashMap<String, Object> hashmap;
//Предварительно создаем наполнитель списка
myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

    for(int i =0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
        //Получаем каждый объект из массива по отдельности
        JSONObject my_obj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
        //Получаем необходимые значения из объектов, по ключевым словам
        title = my_obj.getString("title");
        description = my_obj.getString("description");
        imageURL = my_obj.getString("imageURL");
        //Создаем HashMap
        hashmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
        hashmap.put("title",title);
        hashmap.put("description",description);
        hashmap.put("imageURL",imageURL);
        myList.add(hashmap);

        }
//Теперь создаем адаптер, и заполняем посредством него список
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                  SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(),myList,R.layout.list_item,
                        new String[]{"title","description","imageURL"},    
                        new int[]{R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3}
                        );

                      list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Да вроде все.

**Несколько поправок:

- JSON файл не обязательно должен иметь
     расширение json, а в большинстве
     случаев txt.
- Если Вы захотите    выводить не
     просто URL а само    изображение,
     почитайте про кастомные    адаптеры.

**

Comment: не очень удачный пример хранить и ключ, и значение. когда данных будет много, ключи будут занимать ненужное место.

Comment: А как лучше? Создать класс и хранить в нем, или работать со слабыми ссылками? Тут ему сначала нужно понять как просто распарсить!